# Recipe: How do I use Lombok with Eclipse, Gradle, and Javadocs?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, lombok

Lombok makes Java great, gradle's an awesome, flexible build tool, Eclipse simplifies development significantly, and Javadocs make the world go round.

So when I started a new project, I wanted to figure out how to merge all this magic. Attached is the buildscript I wrote for this purpose, isolated from the other concerns of the project Save it somewhere accessible and include it using `apply from: "path/to/lombok.gradle"`

```
/**
 * Project Lombok, Eclipse, Javadocs and Gradle
 */
// Doing this twice (once here, once in your main project) has no effect on Gradle, but 
// this script depends on the Java and Eclipse plugins
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

// Create a configuration to hold the lombok jar as a dependency
configurations {
    lombok
}
// Add the lombok jar to the configuration
dependencies { 
    lombok 'org.projectlombok:lombok:+' 
}
// Add the lombok configuration to all of the compile classpaths
sourceSets.each{ sourceSet -> 
    sourceSet.compileClasspath += configurations.lombok
    sourceSet.ext.delombok = new File(buildDir, "generated-src/delombok/" + sourceSet.name);
}
// This task will download lombok and install it in your eclipse instance
task installLombok() {
    dependsOn configurations.lombok
} << {
    File jarFile = null;
    configurations.lombok.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.find {
        if ("lombok".equals(it.name)) {
            jarFile = it.file;
        }
    }
    javaexec {
        main="-jar"
        args = [
            jarFile,
            "install",
            "auto"
        ]
    }
}
// Install lombok into eclipse when you set up the project (optional line)
eclipseProject.dependsOn installLombok

// Javadoc doesn't handle lombok'd code, so we have to "delombok" it - that is, expand the 
// neat annotations so that Javadoc can do something with them.
task delombok() {
    dependsOn configurations.compile
    dependsOn configurations.lombok
} << {
    File jarFile = null;
    configurations.lombok.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.find {
        if ("lombok".equals(it.name)) {
            jarFile = it.file;
        }
    }
    sourceSets.each{ sourceSet ->
        def classPath = sourceSet.compileClasspath.files.join(";")
        def delombokPath = sourceSet.ext.delombok
        delombokPath.mkdirs();
        javaexec {
            main = "-jar"
            args jarFile, "delombok"
            if (!classPath.empty) {
                args "-c", classPath
            }
            args "-d", delombokPath
            args sourceSet.allJava.srcDirs
        }
    }
}

javadoc {
    dependsOn delombok
    // At your discretion; I actually use ext.apiDelombok in my case
    source = sourceSets.main.ext.delombok
}
```

Comment: What is the question? What is not working?

Comment: Sorry, this is more of a "Hey, I had a question I couldn't find the answer to on Stack, figured it out, and am sharing the answer. Here you go, Stack."

The question was, "How do I make lombok play nice with a specific development stack"

Comment: It would be better to pose this as a question and add your solution as an answer. It avoids the risk of this being closed and the content lost